# AS3 Flex - users on Windows can select any file on FileReference.browse regardless of FileFilter

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, file-upload, filereference, filefilter

I have this line of code in my app, but when i run it on a Windows pc the user is given the ability to choose between "Custom Files" (which should actually read "clips") and (the default, i guess) "all files". In this case the user can, for instance, upload a wmv clip to my system which cannot handle it. Is there a way to prevent the "all files" option or do I need to build my own filtering system AFTER a selection is made?

on a mac everything is fine

```
myFileReference.browse([new FileFilter("clips","*.swf;*.flv;*.f4v;*.mov;*.mp4")])
```

thanx

Comment: I tried your code, for me worked fine. (Windows 8 FP 11.4)

Comment: thank you Alex. don't you get the ability to choose between "Custom Files" and "All Files"?

Comment: thanx again. this issue is apparently dependent on Windows version, browser type and maybe Flash Player version. I just got a tip to ALWAYS validate no matter what and that is what i will do. cheers

Answer (score 0):

This issue is apparently dependent on Windows version, browser type and maybe Flash Player version. No way to be 100% safe with file type selecting , since Windows users can enter * in the "File name" field and get all files.

I just got a tip to ALWAYS validate no matter what and that is what i will do.

cheers